# MediaMetadataRetriever alternative?

Tags: android, frame

I'm currently using MediaMetadataRetriever and ImageView

```
frame = videoFrame.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
frameView.setImageBitmap(frame);
```

and as advised by the API, it has a delay due to seeking.

Are there any faster alternatives for grabbing frames at specific times from a source video within the device? (I'm using a 1st gen Nexus 7)

Comment: Hi jp.azcueta, i am also facing exactly same issue with FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever on my 1st gen Nexus 7, did you find any better solution or any way to optimize existing code???

Comment: Hi @jp.azcueta, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are an external library called [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever). You can do the same actions like with the other class and it doesn´t fails (Unlike the API´s class that sometimes breaks without a reason at determinated positions). But it is under development and you can´t extract the exact frame and not only the key-frames yet. I suppose in one week it will be ready.

Comment: The person asking question is already using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever and asking for any better solution.

Comment: no, he wasn't using ffmpegmediametadataretriever, he was using the included class mediametadataretriever, it's not the same

Comment: Ok but i am using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever and getting 2 to 7 sec delay in getting frame,  any solution for making it faster.?

Comment: Hi, shridutt kothari did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just fetch one frame or fetch frame one by one for processing?
If the later, I think you should use [MeidaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec).